# Google Cloud RDP not Working (User name & Password didn't work)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rdp

I just created a VM instance on Google Cloud for the very first time,
4 vCPUs 
15GB Ram
Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
SSD 50gb
Access scopes - Allow default access 
Firewall - Allowed bot http/https
Created

After that when am trying to connect thru RDP 
(downloaded the rdp file and put the created password)
its saying
"The user name and password that were used to connect to the remote PC didn't work. Try a different account."
[am using Microsoft Remote Desktop on Mac]

I already tried creating new account & password... still no good..
Please help what could be the issues or solution.
Am using Google Cloud for the first time..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After you create a Windows Instance, you will first need to [generate a password](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-passwords-for-windows-instances#generating_a_password). Once you generate the password, paste it to a text editor. From here, you will need to install the [RDP client for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-mac). From here, you can follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#windows) which will explain how to connect to the Windows Instance using the RDP client you just installed.